# Twitter REST API Vs Twitter Fabric - Twitter Core

Tags: twitter-fabric, twitter-rest-api

I could see, we have two options for integrating twitter in Andriod Apps.

```
1. Twitter REST Api
2. Twitter Fabric - Twitter Core
```

what is the difference between both. Is it only the way to access the data is different ?(Twitter REST Api is calling GET request and we get response. and Twitter Core is an SDK, we just call methods and use it.)

Whether Twitter continue its support for both REST Api and Twitter Fabric.

Note: I know about Twitter4J, which is external api which in turn calls REST APi. please don't provide info for Twitter4J. I don't want any info for external library.

Little confusing which one to use. Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:

I could see single signon as one useful difference. It allows sync the twitter accounts configured in twitter app, which can't be achieved using REST API.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on you what you want to use twitter fabric is just not for integrating twitter,it is a platform which provides other functionalities like crash reports via crashlytics and monetization etc. but you still need to do network requests for getting tweet and other data from twitter and you will need to integrate the sdk in your application which will increase the size of your app.
So if you just want to get the data from twitter and do not want to compromise with the app size you may use the rest apis,but if you think you can benefit from other features provided by the fabric platform then i would definitely recommend to use fabric

Comment: Thanks for taking your time ... I am just comparing Twitter Fabrics's - Twitter Core and REST API. I could see single sign on as a added feature in Twitter Core. Is there any other advantage over it.?

Comment: if apk size doesn't matter to you,i would suggest to use twitter core as it has tweet ui and tweet composer built into it